# Weird directory called Future

Tags: windows, windows-10, usb-flash-drive, virus, date-modified

I've just found a folder on an 8 GB flash stick with some weird stuff going on. The folder is called `Future` and, according to Properties, it's 71.6 GB. Most of the items in it are dated in the future – 2041, 2021, 2028 etc. It won't delete, copy or cut. I'm formatting the disk to get rid of it in case it's a virus or some such nefarious thing, but I'm curious to know how it got there. Take a look at the screen shots.
[image: Explorer Screen]
[image: Properties Screen]

Question: Has anyone else had this happen?

Comment: what was the file system it claims to be? Is there any indication (diskpart) of more than one partition?

Comment: I had a similar problem once, it was a virus. I booted Linux live DVD deleted the virus and then I was able to see normal files in Windows.

Answer (score 0):

Either you're a time traveler, or it may be a virus. Are there any missing files or folders from that drive? If there is, then it's probably a virus that has renamed it all or corrupted the properties of the files (Which might explain the dates and gibberish file names). I recommend you wipe the entire drive and immediately perform a virus-scan of your PC. That's the only thing i could thing of causing something like that.

Edit:

This thread might help as well. Check it out.

[Files names in pen drive turned into gibberish text](https://superuser.com/questions/456815/files-names-in-pen-drive-turned-into-gibberish-text)

Comment: Thanks for the help. The memory stick belonged to a colleague at my office. I ran Windows Defender through it and nothing came up. I've since formatted it and run a virus scan through my colleague's pc.

Really weird. The "FUTURE" folder kinda freaked me out.

Comment: Oh and, they call me the Doctor.