# Virus Damaged my files in USB

Tags: windows, usb-flash-drive

I have a USB Flash which contains many pictures, some days ago I inserted into a pc and viewed those pictures, then the second time when I inserted the USB into the PC, the PC damaged USB files and it shows only one file which is 628 MB and is not opened by windows explorer.exe

The file is shown as **USBC°`¿ä.**

```
PS D:\> dir


    Directory: D:\


Mode                LastWriteTime         Length Name
----                -------------         ------ ----
------       1601-01-01   4:30 AM      654311424 USBC°`¿ä.
-a----       2019-01-25  10:40 PM           1847 Removable Drive (16GB).lnk
```

Can anyone help remove the problem?

Comment: Have you tried restoring the backup of the pictures? What else have you looked in so far? Any websearches you've done?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Files names in pen drive turned into gibberish text](https://superuser.com/questions/456815/files-names-in-pen-drive-turned-into-gibberish-text)

Comment: I have no backups to restore, beside I google the problem but found nothing

Comment: Strange that you found nothing. Maybe your google returns different search results than mine. I found the linked duplicate question, which has an answer, perhaps it is useful to you as well.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I remove malicious spyware, malware, adware, viruses, trojans or rootkits from my PC?](https://superuser.com/questions/100360/how-can-i-remove-malicious-spyware-malware-adware-viruses-trojans-or-rootkit)